# swift how to determine associatedtype in sub protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have a question about protocol associatedtype.

Here is code..

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedtype T: Equatable
}

struct Test {
    let value: TestProtocol
}
```

It has a error.

```
struct Test<T: TestProtocol> {
    let value: T
}
```

And It is ok. but i do not want to use generic in struct.

so I tried..

```
protocol IntTestProtocol: TestProtocol where T == Int  {

}

struct Test {
    let value: IntTestProtocol
}
```

But, this code also has error.

how can i determine TestProtocol's associatedtype in sub protocol?
is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish, why isn't it `Test` that conforms to the protocol? It will be easier to help you if you explain what you want to do.

Comment: @dh0rmfpdlxm: Did you check the answer? Did that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedtype T: Equatable
}

struct TestProtocolContainer<U: Equatable>: TestProtocol {
    typealias T = U
}


struct Test {
    let value: TestProtocolContainer<Int>
}
```

When you declare a protocol with `associatedtype` (which offers static polymorphism, If you are interested in understanding various types of polymorphism and how to achieve it with protocol in swift do give a read to my [blogpost](https://medium.com/@sandeepgb06/polymorphism-using-protocols-in-swift-f9955317d7e4) here).

you cant use that protocol as Concrete type because compiler can't resolve the type of `T` during compilation. (Why during compilation, I said its static polymorphism remember :) )

So that's why compiler expects you to provide it someway to help it resolve the type of `associatedtype` during compilation. One way is by providing `typealias` and specifying the actual data type of `associatedtype`.

example :

```
struct TestProtocolContainer: TestProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
}
```

This works great but then, you would want to make this Generic struct to represent any struct with `Equatable` type. Thats where Generics comes into picture.

```
struct TestProtocolContainer<U: Equatable>: TestProtocol {
```

This represents a Generic structure which uses any `Equatable` type and confirms `TestProtocol` and finally setting

```
typealias T = U
```

Ensures confirmation to `TestProtocol`

Hope this helps

Comment: @dh0rmfpdlxm: Am glad I could help :)